# If statement return value not being returned in Android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Obviously I'm missing something basic here. I have a function where there are return statements all over the function in various if statements. The benefit of that can obviously be debated but I'm running into a situation which I'm not familiar with.

I followed the execution of my program through break points and noticed it proceed as normal to a return statement. However, after reaching that statement it skips the remainder of the function and goes to the return statement at the bottom of the function and returns the value sitting down there. Here are the code snippets, it is hundreds of lines long so I don't want to post the whole thing, just the parts I traced it through:

```
public Location getBestLocation(Context c){ //the header

else if(gps_enabled && passive_enabled && !network_enabled){
        if(hGPSLast != null && hPassive != null){
            if(hGPSLast.getTime() > hPassive.getTime() && System.currentTimeMillis() - hGPSLast.getTime() < 300000){
                return hGPSLast; 
            }else if(hPassive.getTime() > hGPSLast.getTime() && System.currentTimeMillis() - hPassive.getTime() < 300000){
                return hPassive; 
            }else{
                hGPSBest = getGPSloc(c);
                if(hGPSBest.getTime() == hGPSLast.getTime()){
                    if(hPassive.getTime() > hGPSLast.getTime()){
                        return hPassive; 
                    }else{
                        return hGPSLast; 
                    }
                }else{
                    return hGPSBest; 
                }
            }
        }else if(hGPSLast != null && hPassive == null){
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - hGPSLast.getTime() <300000){
                return hGPSLast; 
            }else{
                hGPSBest = getGPSloc(c);
                return hGPSBest; 
            }
        }else if(hPassive != null && hGPSLast == null){
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - hPassive.getTime() < 300000){
                return hPassive; 
            }else{
                hGPSBest = getGPSloc(c);
                if(hGPSBest != null){
                    return hGPSBest;
                }else{
                    return hPassive; 
                }
            }
        }
```

one of the returns in that part of the body is reached, however then the code skips to the very bottom where I have this:

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String best = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    //since you are using true as the second parameter, you will only get the best of providers which are enabled.
    def = lm.getLastKnownLocation(best);
    return def;
```

The code is returning "def" which I defined as a blank holder Location object which I was hoping would be filled by the code just above it if for whatever reason none of the returns in the body were reached. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ouch, with all those nested if-else's, that code is screaming for a refactor.

Comment: a `return` exits the method - always. Either your debugger is playing with your nerves or you misinterpret its results.

Comment: @assylias I think you are right. I did a correction in my code where I assigned the lastknown value first before the search for the new value commenced and it returns the last known value. I think it was an issues where my request for an updated location was being done in a different thread and was not completed yet upon the calling thread asking for the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `return` command immediately ignores all remaining method code and exits the current method it is in. It will immediately return to the former function where the method itself was called.

For example:

```
if(hPassive.getTime() > hGPSLast.getTime()){
    return hPassive; 
}else{
    return hGPSLast; 
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
if(hPassive.getTime() > hGPSLast.getTime()){
    return hPassive; 
}

return hGPSLast;
```

The method will always return either of the two and skip the remaining code.

Comment: Unless there's a `try ... finally` block of course, then all bets are off.

Comment: can be rewritten as: `return hPassive.getTime() > hGPSLast.getTime() ? hPassive : hGPSLast;`